# use dplyr mutate() in programming

Tags: r, tidyverse, nse, dplyr

I am trying to assign a column name to a variable using mutate.

```
df <-data.frame(x = sample(1:100, 50), y = rnorm(50))

new <- function(name){
     df%>%mutate(name = ifelse(x <50, "small", "big"))
}
```

When I run

```
new(name = "newVar")
```

it doesn't work. I know  `mutate_()` could help but I'm struggling in using it together with `ifelse`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're missing a `)` at the end of `mutate`, and `mutate` is spelled incorrectly. Also, be careful in calling a global variable like `df` in your function. It's safer to pass `df` as an argument to your function.

Comment: `mutate_` is getting phased out. Update `dplyr `and type `vignette('programming', 'dplyr')`

Comment: My packages are all up to date.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `dplyr` 0.7.1 and its advances in NSE, you have to `UQ` the argument to `mutate` and then use `:=` when assigning. There is lots of info on programming with `dplyr` and NSE here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html

I've changed the name of the function argument to `myvar` to avoid confusion. You could also use `case_when` from `dplyr` instead of `ifelse` if you have more categories to recode.

```
df <- data.frame(x = sample(1:100, 50), y = rnorm(50))

new <- function(myvar){
    df %>% mutate(UQ(myvar) := ifelse(x < 50, "small", "big"))
}

new(myvar = "newVar")
```

This returns

```
     x        y newVar
1   37  1.82669  small
2   63 -0.04333    big
3   46  0.20748  small
4   93  0.94169    big
5   83 -0.15678    big
6   14 -1.43567  small
7   61  0.35173    big
8   26 -0.71826  small
9   21  1.09237  small
10  90  1.99185    big
11  60 -1.01408    big
12  70  0.87534    big
13  55  0.85325    big
14  38  1.70972  small
15   6  0.74836  small
16  23 -0.08528  small
17  27  2.02613  small
18  76 -0.45648    big
19  97  1.20124    big
20  99 -0.34930    big
21  74  1.77341    big
22  72 -0.32862    big
23  64 -0.07994    big
24  53 -0.40116    big
25  16 -0.70226  small
26   8  0.78965  small
27  34  0.01871  small
28  24  1.95154  small
29  82 -0.70616    big
30  77 -0.40387    big
31  43 -0.88383  small
32  88 -0.21862    big
33  45  0.53409  small
34  29 -2.29234  small
35  54  1.00730    big
36  22 -0.62636  small
37 100  0.75193    big
38  52 -0.41389    big
39  36  0.19817  small
40  89 -0.49224    big
41  81 -1.51998    big
42  18  0.57047  small
43  78 -0.44445    big
44  49 -0.08845  small
45  20  0.14014  small
46  32  0.48094  small
47   1 -0.12224  small
48  66  0.48769    big
49  11 -0.49005  small
50  87 -0.25517    big
```

Comment: `:=` come from `data.table`?

Comment: @Wen No, I think `:=` comes from `rlang`, which is used by the 0.7.1 version of `dplyr`. See here for more info: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html

Answer (score 8):

Following the [dlyr programming vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html), define your function as follows:

```
new <- function(name)
{
    nn <- enquo(name) %>% quo_name()
    df %>% mutate( !!nn := ifelse(x <50, "small", "big"))
}
```

`enquo` takes its expression argument and quotes it, followed by `quo_name` converting it into a string. Since `nn` is now quoted, we need to tell `mutate` not to quote it a second time. That's what `!!` is for. Finally, `:=` is a helper operator to make it valid R code. Note that with this definition, you can simply pass `newVar` instead of `"newVar"` to your function, maintaining `dplyr` style.

```
> new( newVar ) %>% head
    x           y newVar
 1 94 -1.07642088    big
 2 85  0.68746266    big
 3 80  0.02630903    big
 4 74  0.18323506    big
 5 86  0.85086915    big
 6 38  0.41882858  small
```

Comment: accepted meenaparam's answer but your answer is also in no doubt a great one and that will help in another function I am writing. Thanks

Comment: Agreed, I think this is a really useful answer too!

Comment: Finally, after several hours this post solved my issue !

Answer (score 1):

Base R solution

```
df <-data.frame(x = sample(1:100, 50), y = rnorm(50))

new <- function(name){
    df[,name]='s'
    df[,name][df$x>50]='b'
    return(df)
}
```

I am using `dplyr 0.5` so i just combine base R with `mutate`

```
new <- function(Name){

    df=mutate(df,ifelse(x <50, "small", "big"))
    names(df)[3]=Name
    return(df)
}

new("newVar")
```