# Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) :

Tags: r, dplyr

This is the first time I try to write a function with 2 pipes inside so that when I give a name x and variable name y, the results will be aggregrated, joined to the data and removed. When I run my written function, the captioned error message kept on coming up and I have no idea what the problem is.

```
mrr <- function(x, y){ 
  x <- data %>%
   group_by(y) %>%
   summarize(n=n(),
         sum=sum(unit_sales)) 
data <- data %>%
  left_join(x, by="y") %>%
  mutate(str_c(x,y))=(sum-unit_sales)/(n-1) %>%
  select(-one_of(n, sum)) %>%
  rm(x)
}
```

I found the related results when I gave the error message in the search box, but the answers were not related to my problem. Do let me know if you have any thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

There's quite a few things going on here.

First, you don't need to input x into the function...because you are overwriting it immediately. I'm not sure whether you may have meant to input data.

Next, your group_by isn't working because y doesn't exist in your data set...the contents of y are the name of the header. We can use group_by_() to solve this problem.

After that, your mutate command is broken. `mutate(str_c(x,y))` is a complete mutate statement because the () are closed. Also, str_c(x,y) is trying to take a dataframe x and concatenate with a character inside y to get a single character out...this will at best give you a dataframe out and at worse give an error. Better to just specify a column name.

In the same mutate, you may run into an error in `=(sum-unit_sales)/(n-1)`. If n = 1 then you get a divide by zero error output of `NaN`. You can leave this if you want. Just understand what your equation is actually doing.

Getting close, the -one_of() command requires a vector of characters (not just column names. You can either do `select(-n,-sum)` or you can do `select(-one_of(c("n", "sum")))`.

Finally, you don't really need to use `rm(x)` because the variable will be removed when the function is done running anyway.

I had to guess at the name of columns...your names will be different since you didn't give me a sample data set.

---

```
data <- data.frame(d1 = runif(n=10,min=1,max=10),
           d2 = runif(n=10,min=1,max=10),
           unit_sales = runif(n=10,min=1,max=10))

mrr <- function(data, y){ 
  x <- data %>%
    group_by_(.dots = y) %>%
    summarize(n=n(),
     sum=sum(unit_sales)) 
  data <- data %>%
  left_join(x, by=y) %>%
    mutate(someCol=(sum-unit_sales)/(n)) %>%
    select(-one_of(c("n", "sum"))) #%>%
    # rm(x)
}

(mrr(data,"d2"))
```

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for your detailed explanations together with the code. The function works together with the UQ() and := suggested by russellpierce. Are there special reasons why extra brackets are needed to execute the function mrr(data, "d2")?

Comment: Ah, nope. The extra (mrr()) just make the results print to the console window.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting hung up with str_c on the left hand side of your second pipe's mutate. dplyr uses non-standard evaluation, you need to use some tooling to accomplish what you want, vis := and perhaps UQ. See  [use dplyr mutate() in programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45169986/use-dplyr-mutate-in-programming) for a similar problem.

Comment: Hi russellpierce, thanks for your suggestions. The function works, though it takes a long time to execute.