# How to call several variables to group_by in dplyr

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

I am trying to use group_by and summarise with several columns, which will be interactive in a shiny app. So, if I specify the column names inside group_by function it works, but if I create a vector for column names, so it does not work anymore. Here follows an example with Iris dataset:

```r
# Working
iris %>% group_by(Sepal.Length, Species) %>% 
  summarise(
    `Sum.Sepal.Width` = sum(Sepal.Width)
  )

# Not working
columns <- c("Sepal.Length", "Species")
iris %>% group_by(columns) %>% 
  summarise(
    `Sum.Sepal.Width` = sum(Sepal.Width)
  )
```

Thanks.
Wlademir.

Comment: iris %>% group_by(.dots = columns)

Comment: Thank you @Chai! It's working!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47912107/dplyr-group-by-colnames-described-as-vector-of-strings/47912171#47912171), it should work by using `group_by_at()`:

```
columns <- c("Sepal.Length", "Species")
iris %>% group_by_at(columns) %>% 
  summarise(
    "Sum.Sepal.Width" = sum(Sepal.Width)
)
```

Answer (score 3):

[Error in grouped_df_impl(data, unname(vars), drop) :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47721747/error-in-grouped-df-impldata-unnamevars-drop)

```
  columns <- c("Sepal.Length", "Species")

  iris %>% group_by(.dots = columns) %>% 
    summarise(
      `Sum.Sepal.Width` = sum(Sepal.Width)
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

Yet another method is to use `rlang::syms`:

```
iris %>% 
  group_by(!!! rlang::syms(columns)) %>% 
  summarise(
    `Sum.Sepal.Width` = sum(Sepal.Width)
  )
```

Comment: It's the "triple bang" operator in the new "tidy eval" paradigm (`rlang` package) that powers the internals of the tidyverse core packages since `dplyr` `0.6`/`0.7`. A good introduction is: https://cran.r-project.org/package=dplyr/vignettes/programming.html . To read about `!!!` specifically: http://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/quasiquotation.html

Comment: aka "unquote-splice"